# "Function userspace does not return normally" warning in User Mode Linux

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I use User Mode Linux (UML) to debug and hack linux-4.13.4 in Ubuntu 16.04 by using gdb.

I follow the instructions as

1. Get source code

   wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.13.4.tar.xz
2. compile and install

   make mrproper

   make mrproper ARCH=um

   make defconfig ARCH=um

   make menuconfig ARCH=um

   make ARCH=um

   make modules ARCH=um
3. use `Debian Wheezy` file system from http://fs.devloop.org.uk/
4. start UML and debug

I set a breakpoint at `sys_clone` at gdb and type `ls` at UML ==> `root@changeme:~# ls` to reach the breakpoint.

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, SyS_clone (clone_flags=18874385, newsp=0, parent_tidptr=0, child_tidptr=1073896944, tls=0)
    at kernel/fork.c:2139
2139    SYSCALL_DEFINE5(clone, unsigned long, clone_flags, unsigned long, newsp,
```

Then I use `s`, `n`, `finish` to accelerate the gdb process.

1. Trap in the loop

However, I find that the program trap in a loop below until I type `continue`. **Why is that?**

> The loop:

```
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  0x0000000060034663 in handle_trap (local_using_sysemu=<optimized out>, 
    regs=<optimized out>, pid=<optimized out>) at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:173
hard_handler (sig=14, si=0x603c5bf0 <cpu0_irqstack+7152>, p=0x603c5ac0 <cpu0_irqstack+6848>)
    at arch/um/os-Linux/signal.c:161
161 {
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  hard_handler (sig=14, si=0x603c5bf0 <cpu0_irqstack+7152>, 
    p=0x603c5ac0 <cpu0_irqstack+6848>) at arch/um/os-Linux/signal.c:161
<signal handler called>
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  <signal handler called>
0x0000000060034663 in handle_trap (local_using_sysemu=<optimized out>, regs=<optimized out>, pid=<optimized out>)
    at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:173
173     handle_syscall(regs);
(gdb)
```

---

> Full details:

```
Breakpoint 1, SyS_clone (clone_flags=18874385, newsp=0, parent_tidptr=0, child_tidptr=1073899664, tls=0)
    at kernel/fork.c:2139
2139    SYSCALL_DEFINE5(clone, unsigned long, clone_flags, unsigned long, newsp,
(gdb) s
SYSC_clone (tls=<optimized out>, child_tidptr=<optimized out>, parent_tidptr=<optimized out>, 
    newsp=<optimized out>, clone_flags=<optimized out>) at kernel/fork.c:2145
2145        return _do_fork(clone_flags, newsp, 0, parent_tidptr, child_tidptr, tls);
(gdb) n
SyS_clone (clone_flags=18874385, newsp=0, parent_tidptr=<optimized out>, child_tidptr=<optimized out>, 
    tls=<optimized out>) at kernel/fork.c:2139
2139    SYSCALL_DEFINE5(clone, unsigned long, clone_flags, unsigned long, newsp,
(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  SyS_clone (clone_flags=18874385, newsp=0, parent_tidptr=<optimized out>, 
    child_tidptr=<optimized out>, tls=<optimized out>) at kernel/fork.c:2139
0x00000000600211c8 in handle_syscall (r=0x800af370) at arch/um/kernel/skas/syscall.c:32
32          PT_REGS_SET_SYSCALL_RETURN(regs,
Value returned is $5 = 1673
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  0x00000000600211c8 in handle_syscall (r=0x800af370) at arch/um/kernel/skas/syscall.c:32
0x0000000060034663 in handle_trap (local_using_sysemu=<optimized out>, regs=<optimized out>, pid=<optimized out>)
    at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:173
173     handle_syscall(regs);
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  0x0000000060034663 in handle_trap (local_using_sysemu=<optimized out>, 
    regs=<optimized out>, pid=<optimized out>) at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:173
hard_handler (sig=14, si=0x603c5bf0 <cpu0_irqstack+7152>, p=0x603c5ac0 <cpu0_irqstack+6848>)
    at arch/um/os-Linux/signal.c:161
161 {
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  hard_handler (sig=14, si=0x603c5bf0 <cpu0_irqstack+7152>, 
    p=0x603c5ac0 <cpu0_irqstack+6848>) at arch/um/os-Linux/signal.c:161
<signal handler called>
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  <signal handler called>
0x0000000060034663 in handle_trap (local_using_sysemu=<optimized out>, regs=<optimized out>, pid=<optimized out>)
    at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:173
173     handle_syscall(regs);
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  0x0000000060034663 in handle_trap (local_using_sysemu=<optimized out>, 
    regs=<optimized out>, pid=<optimized out>) at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:173
hard_handler (sig=14, si=0x603c5bf0 <cpu0_irqstack+7152>, p=0x603c5ac0 <cpu0_irqstack+6848>)
    at arch/um/os-Linux/signal.c:161
161 {
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  hard_handler (sig=14, si=0x603c5bf0 <cpu0_irqstack+7152>, 
    p=0x603c5ac0 <cpu0_irqstack+6848>) at arch/um/os-Linux/signal.c:161
<signal handler called>
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  <signal handler called>
0x0000000060034663 in handle_trap (local_using_sysemu=<optimized out>, regs=<optimized out>, pid=<optimized out>)
    at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:173
173     handle_syscall(regs);
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  0x0000000060034663 in handle_trap (local_using_sysemu=<optimized out>, 
    regs=<optimized out>, pid=<optimized out>) at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:173
hard_handler (sig=14, si=0x603c5bf0 <cpu0_irqstack+7152>, p=0x603c5ac0 <cpu0_irqstack+6848>)
    at arch/um/os-Linux/signal.c:161
161 {
(gdb) where
#0  hard_handler (sig=14, si=0x603c5bf0 <cpu0_irqstack+7152>, p=0x603c5ac0 <cpu0_irqstack+6848>)
    at arch/um/os-Linux/signal.c:161
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x0000000060034663 in handle_trap (local_using_sysemu=<optimized out>, regs=<optimized out>, 
    pid=<optimized out>) at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:173
#3  userspace (regs=0x800af370) at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:417
#4  0x000000006001ded1 in fork_handler () at arch/um/kernel/process.c:153
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) fin
Run till exit from #0  hard_handler (sig=14, si=0x603c5bf0 <cpu0_irqstack+7152>, 
    p=0x603c5ac0 <cpu0_irqstack+6848>) at arch/um/os-Linux/signal.c:161
<signal handler called>
(gdb) where
#0  <signal handler called>
#1  0x0000000060034663 in handle_trap (local_using_sysemu=<optimized out>, regs=<optimized out>, 
    pid=<optimized out>) at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:173
#2  userspace (regs=0x800af370) at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:417
#3  0x000000006001ded1 in fork_handler () at arch/um/kernel/process.c:153
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  <signal handler called>
0x0000000060034663 in handle_trap (local_using_sysemu=<optimized out>, regs=<optimized out>, pid=<optimized out>)
    at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:173
173     handle_syscall(regs);
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  0x0000000060034663 in handle_trap (local_using_sysemu=<optimized out>, 
    regs=<optimized out>, pid=<optimized out>) at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:173
hard_handler (sig=14, si=0x603c5bf0 <cpu0_irqstack+7152>, p=0x603c5ac0 <cpu0_irqstack+6848>)
    at arch/um/os-Linux/signal.c:161
161 {
(gdb) 
Run till exit from #0  hard_handler (sig=14, si=0x603c5bf0 <cpu0_irqstack+7152>, 
    p=0x603c5ac0 <cpu0_irqstack+6848>) at arch/um/os-Linux/signal.c:161
<signal handler called>
```

## 2. Escape the loop but `Function userspace does not return normally`

Still, I trap in the loop and I only use `next`. I try to `finish` it but

> Function userspace does not return normally

```
393         if (get_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) fin
warning: Function userspace does not return normally.
Try to finish anyway? (y or n) y
Run till exit from #0  userspace (regs=0x800af370) at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:393
```

---

Full detals:

```
Breakpoint 1, SyS_clone (clone_flags=18874385, newsp=0, parent_tidptr=0, child_tidptr=1073899664, tls=0)
    at kernel/fork.c:2139
2139    SYSCALL_DEFINE5(clone, unsigned long, clone_flags, unsigned long, newsp,
(gdb) n
handle_syscall (r=0x800af370) at arch/um/kernel/skas/syscall.c:36
36      syscall_trace_leave(regs);
(gdb) 
37  }
(gdb) 
userspace (regs=0x800af370) at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:438
438             pid = userspace_pid[0];
(gdb) 
439             interrupt_end();
(gdb) 
443                 PT_SYSCALL_NR(regs->gp) = -1;
(gdb) 
355         if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
361         if (put_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
379         CATCH_EINTR(err = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | __WALL));
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
386         regs->is_user = 1;
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
393         if (get_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
399         UPT_SYSCALL_NR(regs) = -1; /* Assume: It's not a syscall */
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
406             switch (sig) {
(gdb) 
438             pid = userspace_pid[0];
(gdb) 
439             interrupt_end();
(gdb) 
443                 PT_SYSCALL_NR(regs->gp) = -1;
(gdb) 
355         if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
361         if (put_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
379         CATCH_EINTR(err = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | __WALL));
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
386         regs->is_user = 1;
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
393         if (get_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
399         UPT_SYSCALL_NR(regs) = -1; /* Assume: It's not a syscall */
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
406             switch (sig) {
(gdb) 
438             pid = userspace_pid[0];
(gdb) 
439             interrupt_end();
(gdb) 
443                 PT_SYSCALL_NR(regs->gp) = -1;
(gdb) 
355         if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
361         if (put_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
379         CATCH_EINTR(err = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | __WALL));
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
386         regs->is_user = 1;
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
393         if (get_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
399         UPT_SYSCALL_NR(regs) = -1; /* Assume: It's not a syscall */
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
406             switch (sig) {
(gdb) 
438             pid = userspace_pid[0];
(gdb) 
439             interrupt_end();
(gdb) 
443                 PT_SYSCALL_NR(regs->gp) = -1;
(gdb) 
355         if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
361         if (put_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
379         CATCH_EINTR(err = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | __WALL));
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
386         regs->is_user = 1;
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
393         if (get_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
399         UPT_SYSCALL_NR(regs) = -1; /* Assume: It's not a syscall */
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
406             switch (sig) {
(gdb) 
438             pid = userspace_pid[0];
(gdb) 
439             interrupt_end();
(gdb) 
443                 PT_SYSCALL_NR(regs->gp) = -1;
(gdb) 
355         if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
361         if (put_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
379         CATCH_EINTR(err = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | __WALL));
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
386         regs->is_user = 1;
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
393         if (get_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
399         UPT_SYSCALL_NR(regs) = -1; /* Assume: It's not a syscall */
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
406             switch (sig) {
(gdb) 
438             pid = userspace_pid[0];
(gdb) 
439             interrupt_end();
(gdb) 
443                 PT_SYSCALL_NR(regs->gp) = -1;
(gdb) 
355         if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
361         if (put_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
379         CATCH_EINTR(err = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | __WALL));
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
386         regs->is_user = 1;
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
393         if (get_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
399         UPT_SYSCALL_NR(regs) = -1; /* Assume: It's not a syscall */
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
406             switch (sig) {
(gdb) 
438             pid = userspace_pid[0];
(gdb) 
439             interrupt_end();
(gdb) 
443                 PT_SYSCALL_NR(regs->gp) = -1;
(gdb) 
355         if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
361         if (put_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
379         CATCH_EINTR(err = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | __WALL));
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
386         regs->is_user = 1;
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
393         if (get_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
399         UPT_SYSCALL_NR(regs) = -1; /* Assume: It's not a syscall */
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
406             switch (sig) {
(gdb) 
438             pid = userspace_pid[0];
(gdb) 
439             interrupt_end();
(gdb) 
443                 PT_SYSCALL_NR(regs->gp) = -1;
(gdb) 
355         if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
361         if (put_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
379         CATCH_EINTR(err = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | __WALL));
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
386         regs->is_user = 1;
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
393         if (get_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
399         UPT_SYSCALL_NR(regs) = -1; /* Assume: It's not a syscall */
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
406             switch (sig) {
(gdb) 
438             pid = userspace_pid[0];
(gdb) 
439             interrupt_end();
(gdb) 
443                 PT_SYSCALL_NR(regs->gp) = -1;
(gdb) 
355         if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
361         if (put_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
379         CATCH_EINTR(err = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | __WALL));
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
386         regs->is_user = 1;
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
393         if (get_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
399         UPT_SYSCALL_NR(regs) = -1; /* Assume: It's not a syscall */
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
406             switch (sig) {
(gdb) 
438             pid = userspace_pid[0];
(gdb) 
439             interrupt_end();
(gdb) 
443                 PT_SYSCALL_NR(regs->gp) = -1;
(gdb) 
355         if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
361         if (put_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
379         CATCH_EINTR(err = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | __WALL));
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
386         regs->is_user = 1;
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
393         if (get_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
399         UPT_SYSCALL_NR(regs) = -1; /* Assume: It's not a syscall */
(gdb) 
401         if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
402             int sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
(gdb) 
404             ptrace(PTRACE_GETSIGINFO, pid, 0, (struct siginfo *)&si);
(gdb) 
406             switch (sig) {
(gdb) 
438             pid = userspace_pid[0];
(gdb) 
439             interrupt_end();
(gdb) 
443                 PT_SYSCALL_NR(regs->gp) = -1;
(gdb) 
355         if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
361         if (put_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
368         local_using_sysemu = get_using_sysemu();
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
370         op = SELECT_PTRACE_OPERATION(local_using_sysemu,
(gdb) 
373         if (ptrace(op, pid, 0, 0)) {
(gdb) 
379         CATCH_EINTR(err = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED | __WALL));
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
386         regs->is_user = 1;
(gdb) 
387         if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, regs->gp)) {
(gdb) 
393         if (get_fp_registers(pid, regs->fp)) {
(gdb) fin
warning: Function userspace does not return normally.
Try to finish anyway? (y or n) y
Run till exit from #0  userspace (regs=0x800af370) at arch/um/os-Linux/skas/process.c:393
```

Comment: Why do you suppose anyone would want to download, decompress and install your source code, and the Debian Wheezy file system? Please make it easy ~ TL;DR. please try to isolate a specific question rather than an exhaustive wall of messages. If your breakpoint is inside a loop, then it will break on every loop, so that the programmer can inspect what is happening, in every loop.

Comment: @Weather Vane The question is not about loop, please read the title carefully, it's about why `Function userspace does not return normally`. Thanks.

Comment: @Weather Vane UML is one part in linux kernel, so everyone use kernel may have already had this part. It is not a special program.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a _[Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/)_?   Or with _[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_?  Your post, in its current state is very unlikely to attract the kind of attention you hope it does.